# embodiment (in)

Tags: meaning, syntax

is "embodiment" or "embody" ever construed with "in"?
How is "in" used in this case? I would have expected a "by".

*the embodiment of the poetic voice in a singer added a musical appeal*

Thank you,
Katerina

Comment: Katerina, I dont get the question. because as much as I know _"**Embodiment**"_ comes with **of** like your sentence there :  _**the embodiment of the poetic voice**_  and I think the phrase _"in a singer"_ is totally unrelated, I can say _"**the embodiment of Christ in my mind**"_ or _**the embodiment of Christ by her art**_. it all depends on the context.

Comment: Your text is fine. Check out some written instances of [*X **is embodied in** Y*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+embodied+in%22) if you need reassurance.